# DjangoRest - http request with csrftoken return user.isauthenticated() false

Tags: django, rest, curl, httprequest, django-rest-framework

So I have login view, that works great and returns a token.

```
@csrf_exempt
def login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username', None)
    password = request.POST.get('password', None)

    if username is not None and password is not None:
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
                if not created:
                    created = datetime.datetime.now()
                return json_response({
                    'token': token.token,
                    'username': user.username
                })
            else:
                return json_response({
                    'error': 'Invalid User'
                }, status=400)
        else:
            return json_response({
                'error': 'Invalid Username/Password'
            }, status=400)
    else:
        return json_response({
            'error': 'Invalid Data'
        }, status=400)
elif request.method == 'OPTIONS':
    return json_response({})
else:
    return json_response({
        'error': 'Invalid Method'
    }, status=405)
```

The curl line is:

```
curl -X POST -d "username=root&password=myPassword" http://localhost:80/api/login/
```

and the result of that line is great:

```
{"username": "root", "token": "3dfdcd6b2abeb432131c734f82a737505ee3110d"}
```

After i login via that httprequest I would like to send GET request to the server to get a view.

My view example

```
from django.contrib.auth.middleware import get_user
def list_orders(request):
   # check if authenticated else will exit
   if not get_user(request).is_authenticated():
    return ResponseError('authentication or permission failure')
   ...
   ...
```

**this view always returns the not authenticated error :(**

my http request exmple:

```
curl http://localhost:80/orders/ -d "csfrmiddletoken=3dfdcd6b2abeb432131c734f82a737505ee3110d"
```

returns:

```
{"status": "failed", "details": "authentication or permission failure"}
```

It is very importent to me to NOT use cookies ! so please dont suggest to add -b -c params to my curl line.

**what should i do to use the token from my login view to get requests?**

Thank you !

**EDIT:**
I solved that problem by 2 streps:
one i used another function to make sure i get a token:

```
def token_required(func):
    def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        auth_header = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)
        if auth_header is not None:
            tokens = auth_header.split(' ')
            if len(tokens) == 2 and tokens[0] == 'Token':
                token = tokens[1]
                try:
                    request.token = Token.objects.get(token=token)
                    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
                except Token.DoesNotExist:
                    return json_response({
                        'error': 'Token not found'
                    }, status=401)
        return json_response({
            'error': 'Invalid Header'
        }, status=401)

    return inner
```

second, i changed my httprequest:

```
 curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:80/orders/ -H 'Authorization: Token 3dfdcd6b2abeb432131c734f82a737505ee3110d'
```

**BUT** now even when Im logged to django over the web interface and I try to access to that link I get an error that I dont have valid header.
How can I make sure that both ways (web interface) and token via httprequest will work together?

Answer (score 1):

The token returned by your login view is not a csrf token, so I am not sure why you have `csfrmiddletoken` in your request.

Secondly, the [rest framework docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) say that the token should be sent as a header, not as data in the request.

Try the following:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/ -H 'Authorization: Token 3dfdcd6b2abeb432131c734f82a737505ee3110d'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still gets the same error even when I try this line

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you manage to get it working :)